# How to calculate length of unique values per column in a data frame in r programming

Tags: r

I have a data frame in r, and I need to calculate the number of unique values per column. Some of the columns are of numeric and factor type. Help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `n_distinct` with `map` to achieve that. Here is an example:

```
library(tidyverse) 
iris %>% map(n_distinct)
```

Answer (score 6):

Let's say that your data is stored in a data frame called `df`.

You can get the unique elements in each column using

```
sapply(df, unique)
```

You can get the number of unique elements in each column using

```
sapply(sapply(df, unique), length)
```

Using the `iris` data set as an example:

```
df = iris
> sapply(sapply(df, unique), length)
Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width      Species 
          35           23           43           22            3
```

Comment: You can save one `sapply` by doing `sapply(df, function(x) length(unique(x)))`

Comment: @JilberUrbina That's true, I didn't think of that. That's a clever solution! Thank you for sharing.

Answer (score 4):

This will work using base R:

```
minifun <- function(col) {length(unique(col))}
lapply(iris, minifun)
```

Answer (score 3):

For completeness, a `data.table` solution

```
as.data.table(iris)[, lapply(.SD, uniqueN)]
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#1:           35          23           43          22       3
```

Comment: Why the downvote? This addresses OPs question, and offers a *fast* `data.table`-based solution.

Comment: I also received a downvote for providing a correct result (which is in line with best practices).